# Is O(LogN) == O(3LogN)?

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I just started a course on Asymptotic Analysis and in one of our assignments I am supposed to add functionality to a function without changing the complexity. The complexity is log(N). The homework guideline asks me specifically to change the runtime by a 'constant'. Would making it 3Log(N) be considered changing it by a constant?

Comment: Did you forget the exact definition of `O(log N)` ? Go back to the definition to understand that the answer is trivially *yes*

Comment: Can you show how did you end up getting `3log(n)`?

Comment: I believe that adding something, like (constant + log(N)) would be considered adding a constant factor, whereas 3LogN would be multiplying. Although I know by definition that O(3LogN) = o(LogN), I feel my instructor meant the additive form. The thing is I did not want to take any chances with my assignment so I wanted to clarify with more knowledgeable folks.

Comment: I think you need to look up what "factor" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, more specifically, this would be changing it by a multiplicative constant. You could also change it by an additive constant like `log(N)+5`.

Comment: Yes, this thing is changing an algorithm by a multiple of something like `3` is highly unlikely unless you do something like run a nested loop just 3 times which again might not be the optimal solution.

Comment: The original function involved adding an element to a binary search tree. To complete my assignment, I had to modify the code so as to traverse the tree not once, but twice. Would that be 2LogN?

Comment: @noMAD It's not uncommon to need to do something in a constant number passes over a data structure, or to add a constant number of operations inside the iteration.

Comment: @ZachSchnider: You are traversing your tree once at a time no matter how many times you do it. So, it would still end up being `O(log n)` or in the case of traversing the entire tree it should be `O(n)`.

Comment: @ZachSchnider Yes. What noMAD is alluding to is probably the fact that `O(2 log n)` is still `= O(log n)`.

Comment: @trutheality: How can parsing a tree twice cost you `O(2Log n)`? Its the Asymptotic time analysis.

Comment: @noMAD, as far as asymptotic time analysis is concerned, passing it **once** is `O(9001 log n)` because the constant doesn't matter. Passing it twice can take `2 log n` operations, which is `O( log n ) = O( 2 log n ) = O( 9001 log n )`.

Comment: What about `O(log n)` and `O(log n^2)`. By properties of logarithms isn't `2 log n` equal to `log n^2`? I'm not sure what I'm saying even makes sense.

Comment: @nikhil That's right: `O( log(n^2) ) = O(2 log n) = O(log n)`. But don't confuse `log(n^2)` with `(log n)^2`, because those don't have the same asymptotic complexity.